# NullPointer in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a AlertDialog in a Android Activity that increments or decrements the value in the TextView.

I used this code to insert the Android XML in the AlertDialog (enter_quantity is the name of the xml file)

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View enterQuantityView = li.inflate(R.layout.enter_quantity, null); 

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogEnterQuantity = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialogEnterQuantity.setView(enterQuantityView);
```

I've input the functionalities in(CreateListSearch.java)

```
final Button btAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Add);
final Button btSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Sub);
final TextView tvQuantity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEnterQuantity_Quantity);

btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int AddOne = Integer.parseInt(tvQuantity.getText().toString()) + 1;
        tvQuantity.setText("" + AddOne);
    }
});

btSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        int SubOne = Integer.parseInt(tvQuantity.getText().toString()) - 1;
        if (SubOne >= 0){
            tvQuantity.setText("" + SubOne);
        }else{
            tvQuantity.setText("0");
        }


    }
});
```

But a NullPointerException occured at line "btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {"

What can I do to fix his solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHange to

```
 final Button btAdd = (Button)enterQuantityView.findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Add);
 final Button btSub = (Button)enterQuantityView.findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Sub);
 final TextView tvQuantity = (TextView)enterQuantityView.findViewById(R.id.tvEnterQuantity_Quantity);
```

I believe the button is in `enter_quantity.xml`.

You need to use the infalted view object to `findViewById` as it looks for a view in the current inflated layout

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look here

```
final Button btAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Add);
final Button btSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Sub);
final TextView tvQuantity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEnterQuantity_Quantity);
```

make changes to

```
final Button btAdd = (Button)enterQuantityView.findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Add);
final Button btSub = (Button)enterQuantityView.findViewById(R.id.btEnterQuantity_Sub);
final TextView tvQuantity = (TextView)enterQuantityView.findViewById(R.id.tvEnterQ
```

on this sample code, write yours alert dialog in the given way that it will be easy to understand

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and show [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) from Builder first.

Also get view references from the first node, which is enterQuantityView.

```
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View enterQuantityView = li.inflate(R.layout.enter_quantity, null); 

 final AlertDialog.Builder dialogEnterQuantity = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
 dialogEnterQuantity.setView(enterQuantityView);
 AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogEnterQuantity.create();
 alertDialog.show();
```